# Passing a select option to a controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass a select option to a controller this way

**product.blade.php**

```
Category <br>
<select name="category_name" id="">
 @foreach ($categories as $category)
   <option value="{{ $category->category_name}}">{{ $category->category_name}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select><br>
```

**ProductController.php**

```
$product = new Product;
$category_name = $request->category_name;
$category_id =DB::table('categories')->where('category_name',$request->category_name)->value('id');
$vendor_id = DB::table('vendors')->where('user_id',$user_id)->value('id');

echo $category_name;
```

It does not echo anything yet. What Have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you add the code where you are actually sending the value?

Comment: I am getting the selected category from products.blade.php and sending it to the controller which fetches the id from the database.  The category name does not reach the controller yet other fields get to the controller